# Bug in Path division with circle?

Tags: inkscape

I have these two objects:

[image]

I wish to do *Division* on them, so first, based on a tutorial I first combined them:

[image]

Then I have put a larger rectangle behind them:

[image]

Then with everything selected I did the Division, but it is working pretty strange:

[image]

I would expect a correct circle here, like this:

[image]

Both the circle and the rectangle were drawn with InkScape's default tools, no nasty modifications has been made.

InkScape version is the latest stable (I believe): 1.2.

Comment: You should contact inkscape bug tracker, we cant actually do anything for bugs.

Comment: I can't actually reproduce this problem with Inskcape 1.2.  [The result](https://imgur.com/bKRDHPB) is as expected.  Can you try zooming in or out. Might just be a rendering bug. Another thing to check is that your circle is a closed path, make sure to [click the Whole Ellipse button](https://imgur.com/w8WqpUe) just in case.

Comment: Might be worth making sure of the exact version.  I've found a few bugs in 1.2.1 that make it unusable for me (not this one, but others that affect redraw speed on screen). I Had to go back to 1.2

Comment: I guess I accidentally drag the small circle handle on the circle object making it an opened arc (some day in past). Then I have updated Inkscape and it remembered this setting from the old instance, and by default it started drawing arcs instead of circles. Thank you!